# YouTube iframe API for mobile devices issue

Tags: youtube-api

I am looking to develop a custom YouTube player for a playlist within my YouTube channel and came across the YouTube Iframe API.

I have successfully implemented a player that works on desktop however it is causing some what of a challenge to get working on mobile devices. According to the documentation the Iframe API is the right one to use if you plan to show YouTube Videos on mobiles as it can detect for HTML5 video support, however when I try my code and even the demo code within the documentation as shown here

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started

An image of the video loads in the mobile browser but when i go to play it, I just get a grey Quicktime image with a cross through the play button on IOS devices and it falls back to flash on Android.

I have tried adding ?html5=1 to the end of the iframe url to force HTML 5 mode and also opted into the HTML5 trial by Youtube on both desktop and each mobile browser but has no effect on the outcome.

When loading the pages in Desktop It does load in HTML5 mode, so why not in mobile?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

J

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a 'brand channel' (enabled to have a custom tab) authorised by YouTube, you then have to request a custom gadget which displays a mobile gadget available to the mobile web version of Youtube. This doesn't work in the Youtube App for iOS.